# Controller won't connect to PS4 after pairing it to Chromebook

Tags: ps4, controllers

I have a PlayStation 4 controller and I paired it to my Chromebook but now it won't connect to my PlayStation 4. I have reset it but it still doesn't work.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting the controller to the PS4 with a USB cable?
https://support.playstation.com/s/article/DualShock-4-Troubleshooting